# Squid only works when run with 'sudo'

Tags: networking, proxy, squid

I want to run may instances of `squid` proxies. But I am only able to connect with them when squid is started with sudo. In the squid config I have:

```
access_log none
cache_store_log none
cache_log /dev/null
```

```
$ squid -n squida -f /tmp/squid_80fm8klt.conf                                                                                                              
$ curl --proxy http://localhost:3129  https://httpbin.org/ip                                                                                                   
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3129: Connection refused
$ sudo squid -n squida -f /tmp/squid_80fm8klt.conf                                                                                                         
WARNING: Cannot write log file: none
none: Permission denied
         messages will be sent to 'stderr'.
$ curl --proxy http://localhost:3129  https://httpbin.org/ip                                                                                                     
{
  "origin": "92.119.18.XX"
}
```

I'm on a Fedora 32 system.

Full config:

```
http_access allow all

coredump_dir /var/spool/squid3

refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern (Release|Packages(.gz)*)$      0       20%     2880
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320

access_log none
cache_store_log none
cache_log /dev/null

never_direct allow all
cache_peer zzz.nordvpn.com parent 89 3130 tls login=xXx:yYy
http_port 3129
```

Comment: It looks like it's trying to write a file called "`none`". Have you read `man -k squid`? What port are you using? Ports under 1000 are privileged.

Comment: The description of [`cache_log`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v4/cfgman/cache_log.html) doesn't show `none` as a supported value (compare with [`access_log`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v4/cfgman/access_log.html), which does).

Comment: @waltinator The local port which squid listens to is 3129. Squid itself listens/forwards to another upstream proxy on port 89. Sending logs to `none` is from here: https://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidLogs#How_can_I_disable_Squid.27s_log_files.3F

Comment: @muru I have changed it to `/dev/null` as per the wiki and I still have the same issue

Comment: Using squid 4.15 on Arch Linux, I don't get your error about `none`. However, `squid` run as my user does fail, but debug logging showed that that was because it could not write to the PID file. Run `squid -n squida -f /tmp/squid_80fm8klt.conf -N -d 1` to see what your squid is failing over.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @muru, running squid with `squid -N -d 1` reveals that

```
2021/07/27 03:20:12| FATAL: failed to open /run/squid.pid: (13) Permission denied
    exception location: File.cc(190) open
```

The solution is to place the pidfile in another directory, or to avoid creating it, as per http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/pid_filename/
place this in the config:

```
pid_filename none
```